# Symfony 3.2 parameters not being passed to service's __construct method

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I am trying to create a service that's essentially a wrapper for Stripe. In the construct method, I want to pass in the api secret and publishable key through the service's construct method which is set as environment variables in a .env file. But every time I run phpunit tests on this wrapper, I'm getting this error:

```
Missing argument 1 for AppBundle\Util\StripeService::__construct(), called in /Users/name/Sites/app/tests/AppBundle/Util/StripeServiceTest.php
```

Here is my setup:

```
# .env
SYMFONY__STRIPE_SECRET=''
SYMFONY__STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE=''

# config_test.yml
parameters:
stripe.secret: '%env(stripe_secret)%'
stripe.publishable: '%env(stripe_publishable)%'

services:
    app.stripe_service:
        class: AppBundle\Util\StripeService
        arguments: ['%stripe.secret%', '%stripe.publishable%']

# StripeService.php
namespace AppBundle\Util;
class StripeService {
    public function __construct($secretKey, $publishableKey)
    {
        $this->secretKey = $secretKey;
        $this->$publishableKey = $publishableKey;
    }

# StripeServiceTest.php
namespace Tests\AppBundle\Util;

use AppBundle\Util\StripeService;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class StripeServiceTest extends TestCase {

    protected function setUp()
    {
        require_once realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../../app/AppKernel.php');
        $kernel = new \AppKernel('test', true);
        $kernel->boot();
    }

    public function testFindEvent()
    {
        $stripe = new StripeService();
        $stripe->findEvent('test');
    }
}

# AppKernel.php
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');

        # This is where I am loading in the variables from .env
        try {
            (new Dotenv\Dotenv(realpath(__DIR__ . '/..')))->load();
            $envParameters = $this->getEnvParameters();
            $loader->load(function($container) use($envParameters) {
            $container->getParameterBag()->add($envParameters);
            });
        } catch (Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException $e) {
        }
    }
}
```

I followed the instructions about service containers in the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html) and followed [this blog post] on using vlucas/phpdotenv to grab variables from the .env file. Am I missing something or did I set something up incorrectly that when my test initializes `new StripeService()` that it can't grab the parameters listed in `config_test.yml`?

Comment: The php new operator knows nothing about the Symfony container.  You will need to pass the parameters directly in your test case.  Or pull the service from the kernel's container.  I suspect you will have other problems as well.  It sort of looks like you are trying to test the stripe interface itself and not your stripe service.  Two completely different things.

Comment: @Cerad Thanks Cerad. The StripeService will be handling errors in a more uniform way. For this initial testing, I just wanted to make sure that it would be instantiated with the correct API key and publishable key.

When you say "pull service from kernel's container" do you mean we can only access this service with the params by doing something such as: $container->get('app.stripe_service')?

Comment: Yep.  Both of the answers below show how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The StripeServiceTest should look like this:

```
class StripeServiceTest extends TestCase {

protected $container;

protected function setUp()
{
    require_once realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../../app/AppKernel.php');
    $kernel = new \AppKernel('test', true);
    $kernel->boot();
    $this->container = $kernel->getContainer();
}

public function testFindEvent()
{
    $stripe = $this->container->get('app.stripe_service');
    $stripe->findEvent('test');
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to instantiate the class ( `new StripeService()` ) without passing the required parameters defined in your `StripeService::__constuctor()`

If you want to use the service instance which you have defined in your `config_test.yml` you need to make usage of the "Container"

```
...
$stripeService = $kernel->getContainer()->get('app.stripe_service');
```

This will give you the instance with your parameters you have defined.